# Xamarin Form Custom Map - Unable to navigate to another page in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I have a requirement where I need to navigate to another Activity or page created in my core project of my PCL app. All the sample I checked takes me to a website using the URI. What should i change in the code below that will allow me to navigate to different pages in my app when the pin is clicked?

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    ...

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "what code should I change"? Is something not working? What? What should happen and what actually does? Why have you tagged your question with google maps when it doesn't have anything apparent to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

You generally call back to your custom map in the PCL and let it handle the navigation.

The way I do it is by:

1) Add a bindable property of type ICommand to the custom map

```
   public static readonly BindableProperty MapClickedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(MapClickedCommand),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(CustomMap));

    public ICommand MapClickedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MapClickedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapClickedCommandProperty, value); }
    }
```

2) Add a public method to the custom map that will be called by the custom renderer

```
public void RaiseMapClicked(Url url)
{
    MapClickedCommand?.Execute(url);
}
```

3) In the custom renderer in your OnInfoWindowClick call the public method

```
var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
var formsMap = Element as CustomMap;
formsMap.RaiseMapClicked(url);
```

This allows you to bind a command to the custom map and handle the Url in your view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message from your custom MapRenderer whenever a pin is clicked [using the Xamarin MessagingCenter](https://montemagno.com/how-to-use-xamarinforms-messaging-center/). See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032659/15904).